# How to get tikzexternalize to work with this thesis template?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I'm currently trying to get this PhD thesis template (http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/) to work with tikzexternalize since I have many pictures which take very long to convert and I want to outsource this as much as possible. I've narrowed everything down as much as I could and built a MWE, which is accessible here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlnhqvohbapqmej/MWE.zip?dl=0

The code runs without errors with pdflatex as long as the picture (test.tikz in Chapter1/figs) is on the first page. Once the picture goes to the second page (try to uncomment \clearpage in Chapter1/chapter1.tex) I get the following error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "TikzFigs/thesis-figure0" "\def\tikzextern
alrealjob{thesis}\input{thesis}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'TikzF
igs/thesis-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that
 you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.
 Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the com
mand simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'TikzFigs/thesis-figure0.log
'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

This doesn't help much. The log file of the figure (TikzFigs/thesis-figure0.log) gives this error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 12.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.12 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the macros used in the class file of the template but I'm not able to pin down what the problem is. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to include your MWE here.

Comment: Hello, I just tried it but the MWE has more code than the limit of characters here, so how should I proceed?

Comment: Are you sure that you can't remove anything and still reproduce the problem? You don't need to include the class here, since we've got a link for that and including the whole thing will probably push it over the limit. It is possible not to be able to produce an MWE within the character limit, but it takes a pretty unusual kind of problem for that to happen.

Comment: the class file is the problem, it's very long and since I didn't know what the problem in the class file is, I couldn't shorten it. but Ulrike Fischer posted the solution to the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change this line in your class file (around line 730):

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

to

```
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}}
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, it works! could you please explain shortly what the problem actually is? i'm interested!

Comment: I didn't try to analyze what happens this would take too much time. I found the probablematic line by shortening the class. If the answer works you should accept it.

Comment: I accept it of course. I'm just interested how you found it. I tried for hours finding the problem. How did you go about shortening the class file? You surely used some kind of algorithm to find exactly this line, right? I just didn't know how to isolate the problem in the class file. So if you could give me some insight into how you did it I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I put `\endinput` in various places to narrow down the problematic part and then did some in- and out commenting. It didn't take me very long, but I'm rather good at this sort of things -- I have a lot training.

Comment: This worked for me too. Mad.